# Windows: send midi note over command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, midi

does anybody know of a way to send a simple midi note from the command line?
I've checked out [sendmidi](http://www.sreal.com:8000/~div/midi-utilities-for-windows/), which works but I can't seem to recieve the send note and [midicom](https://code.google.com/p/midicom/), which doesn't work on 64bit.

All I really need is something I can call like

```
midi <channel>
```

Any hints?

I'm using midiRTP to deliver the midi data over an adhoc network, but also tried sendmidi locally using loopBee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get sendmidi to work!
For the record, for a standard midi message this is the correct syntax:

```
sendmidi --out 1 --note-on 0 0
```

This will send note on on port 1, pitch 0, velocity 0.